# A little problem in handling 2-D arrays with class

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array

```
class linklist4x4
{
 private:

  struct node4x4
  {
    double data[4][4];
    node4x4 *link;
  }*p;

 public:

 linklist4x4();
        void append( double* num );
        void add_as_first( double* num );
        void addafter( int c, double* num );
        //void del( double* num );
        void display();
        int count();
 double* getdata(int c);
        ~linklist4x4();
};
```

The above is my class declaration.

Now below is a function declaration.

```
void linklist4x4::append(double* num)
{
 node4x4 *q,*t;

 if( p == NULL )
 {
  p = new node4x4;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    p->data[i][j]=num[i][j];//error line
  p->link = NULL;
 }
 else
 {
  q = p;
  while( q->link != NULL )
                        q = q->link;

  t = new node4x4;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    t->data[i][j]=num[i][j];//error line
  t->link = NULL;
  q->link = t;
 }
}
```

When i try to compile, it gives me an error saying that "error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type" at the marked commented lines as shown.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: People should really read the C++FAQ. This is one of those questions that come and go each so often and are well explained there - how to implement . http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ (in particular read 13.10 on how to create a matrix class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the method append to take a 1-D array of type double. But in the function you are making use of it as a 2-D array.

The data in each of your link list node is a 2-D array of double.

So your all your member functions should accept a 2-D array of double as argument.

Change:

```
void append( double* num );
void add_as_first( double* num );
void addafter( int c, double* num );
```

to

```
void append( double num[][4] );
void add_as_first( double num[][4] );
void addafter( int c, double num[][4] );
```

Answer (score 5):

The `num` passed in is a single `double` pointer, but you are trying to index it with two subscripts. If you are really passing in a 4x4 `double` array, change the function signature to indicate that it is such.

Answer (score 2):

"num" has a single indirection so you can't dereference it twice. Declare is as

```
double (*num)[4]
```

if you want it to accept a 2D matrix so that you can apply [] to it twice.

Comment: I would go for `double num[][4]` since that's clearer in this context, but props for mentioning the level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing `num` as if it were a 2D array or double pointer, while it is only one level deep.

`double* num`

`num[i][j]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use num[i*4+j] for accessing the data you require.